# Weird PHP session issue, session variable is still there after restarting the browser

Tags: php

`Logout.php` script:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['admin_uname']);
session_regenerate_id();

$_SESSION['success_msg'] = "<strong>You've been logged out.</strong>";
header('location: //domain.com/admin/login');
exit;
```

`Login.php` (part):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin_uname']) && !empty($_SESSION['admin_uname'])) {
  goPage("//domain.com/admin/dashboard"); // goPage is a selfmade PHP function that checks whether value is self, home or an url and redirects the user to the correct location
  exit;
}
```

`Core.php` // the core is above all the content on every page. The script below checks whether the user is on a protected page, these pages are defined in the `$protectedpages` array.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin_uname']) && !empty($_SESSION['admin_uname'])) {
  $admin_uname = $_SESSION['admin_uname'];
} else {
  $protectedpages = array("contact", "offertes");
  $currentpage = str_replace(".php", "", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
  if (in_array($currentpage, $protectedpages)) {
    $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Your session either expired or you are not logged in. Please try again.';
    header('location: //domain.com/admin/login');
    exit;
  }
}
```

When the user is logging out by going to the `logout.php` page. closes the browser, reopens the browser, goes back to `login.php` the `if (isset($_SESSION['admin_uname'])` part of the code on the `login.php` page is being executed, the user will pass by the `core.php` and return back to the `login.php` page with the message `Your session either expired or you are not logged in. Please try again.` because the `core.php` doesn't detect the user to be logged in or at least it doesn't detect `$_SESSION['admin_uname']` is set or not empty. Normally you would expect this kind of behavior to trigger an infinite loop but it doesn't do that.

I hope it all makes sense and I narrowed it down to the code above. There is no other part of the script that can set the `$_SESSION['admin_uname']` variable.

Comment: Why are you starting and destroying the session, and then starting it again? If it's to send data back to the logout screen, you could get the desired effect using cookies?

Comment: @Will why would I want to set a cookie if it's much easier with PHP sessions? Once the the message has been displayed the `session['success_msg']` gets unset right after.

Comment: Have you tried using this solution from the documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php#107089

Comment: @Will just did. still getting the same result :(